# Query for joining another MySQL table, counting rows and specific fields

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm no MySQL specialist, so I need and advice for making a single query, joining another table and counting all joined rows as well rows with specific fields

This is my initial query:

```
SELECT e.id, e.event_fr, e.max_capacity, count(s.id) as subscriptions
FROM events e
INNER JOIN events_subscriptions s ON s.activity = e.id
GROUP BY e.id, e.event_fr
ORDER BY e.id ASC
```

Basically I'm trying to find out (count) number of subscriptions for given event.

But every subscription event also has a field called "waiting_list" which can be either 0 or 1. It tells me whether or not current subscribed person is on the waiting list or not.

I need to be able to count those as well to find out how many people are on the waiting list for the given event:

id: 3,
event_fr: Yoga & relaxation,
suscriptions: 14
waiting_list: 3

id: 4,
event_fr: Judo,
suscriptions: 10
waiting_list: 5

etc..
I understand a super outer join with subquery is missing..
Is it possible to be able to additionally count "waiting_list" on joined table? (e.g WHERE waiting_list = 1)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, you don't really need that additional count, because you already know what the event's max capacity is. So, you just have to subtract the subscriptions count from the e.max_capacity value, and that is the number of people currently on the waiting list.